# How to convert MySQL blob image to base64 string in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, base64, blob

I have a BLOB image in Cloud Server and I want to display it using `Tkinter.Label()`

Before diving into code I must tell blob file exist in mysql table and `record` itself does store
a row from table correctly. `records[0][2]` stands for `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwI...`

Here is the code snippet:

```
global img

#Connecting Server
mydb= mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)


#Fetching Blob Image to Record
sql_fetch_blob_query = """SELECT * from my-Table where id = %s"""
emp_id=4
cursor.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query, (emp_id,))
record = cursor.fetchall()

#Base64 Encoding
base64_encoded= base64.b64encode(record[0][2])
base64_encoded_string= base64_encoded.decode('utf-8')

#Displaying on Tkinter
root=tk.Tk()
img=tk.PhotoImage(data=base64_encoded_string)
myLabel= tk.Label(root,image=img)
myLabel.pack()
root.mainLoop()
```

And here is the error i get:

`_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize image data` on`img=tk.PhotoImage(data=base64_encoded_string)`line

---

I tried changing that line to `img=tk.PhotoImage(data=record[0][2])` and still the same error.

EDIT:

I print `record[0][2]` before encoding and the output is: `b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\`

Comment: Based on your update section, the image in the database is the raw data.  So you should use `base64_encoded` in `tk.PhotoImage()`: `img = tk.PhotoImage(data=base64_encoded)`.

Comment: From your update section, the image in the database is in JPEG format which is not supported by `tk.PhotoImage()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

So it turns out my blob image that I store in cloud server is something `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage()` can use. In other word `img=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=record[0][2])` is the line I needed! Then I put a label on my tkinter GUI which is `myLabel= tk.Label(root,image= img)` AND changed `root.mainLoop()` to `root.mainloop()`.

Now I can upload image files to cloud server and display it on my GUI whenever I want.